# Could my ScriptManager (Ajax) actually affecting the actual outcome of my jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this jQuery script that displays a certain`<td>`depending on the value selected of my dropdownlist

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lblMBRY').hide();
        $('#ddlMBRY').hide();

        $('#lblMBRO').hide();
        $('#txtMBRO').hide();

        var i = document.getElementById("<%=ddlMBR.ClientID%>")
        var valueMBR = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;

        var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlMailJob.ClientID%>")
        var valueMailJob = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


        if (valueMBR == "Y") {
            $('#lblMBRY').show();
            $('#ddlMBRY').show();

            if (valueMailJob == "Others") {
                $('#lblMBRO').show();
                $('#txtMBRO').show();

                $('#lblMBRY').hide();
                $('#ddlMBRY').hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

It works but there's 1 problem - for every selected value I pick from the dropdownlist requires a refresh in order for the`<td>`to show or hide.  What's going on?  I'm using the jquery-1.11.0.js and the dropdropdownlist isn't using any ajax, it's just my above dropdownlist that uses ajax.

Comment: off topic, but you can simplify this: `var valueMailJob = $('#<%=ddlMailJob.ClientID%>').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an onchange event:

```
$('MySelect').change( function() {
   // Do stuff
});
```